# Can we make view dynamic in xpage..?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Can we make  dynamic.I cant use extension lib "dynamic viewpanel control" to achive this. First of all.. is that possible to achive my requirement using ???????

Thanks in advance..

Comment: could u please describe what do u want to do? 'view dynamic' what is it?

Comment: I have a set of view names as a link on left navigation menu .On click of each link i have to display the respective documents in a view pannel.

Comment: If you can't use the Extlib I suggest you use the officially supported UpgradePack1 (also fully included in the upcoming R9.0). And buy your admin a beer

Answer (score 2):

You have several options: you can compute the view name. Then use the column index rather than the column name, so any view renders.
Or, better, have a look at the extlib/updatepack's dynamic view control

Comment: Thanks..I cannot use Extension Lib.. let me try with the column indx.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this similar question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881944/do-i-need-a-separate-xpage-for-each-of-my-30-notes-views